# Why is my json encoded?

Tags: json, jquery

I have the following code which I post a bunch of JSON data to an ASHX file where I will process this data. Somehow the JSON is encoded and I have no clue what encoded it.

```
 $.ajax({        
    url: '/save_objects_channels.ashx',
    data: jsonParams,
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'json',                                
    success: function(data) {                                  

    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){

    },
    complete: function() {

    }
});
```

Here is my sample json that I posted (I generate this as string):

```
var jsonParams = '[ { objectID: 333, channelID: 3, supplierId: 2, checked: true },{ objectID: 444, channelID: 4, supplierId: 5, checked: true } ]';
```

[image]

Comment: Why exactly is that a problem?

Comment: the encoded part, that is causing problems

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQuery encoded it. You chose to send it as a GET request (which is the default for `.ajax()`), which transfers all data in the URL as part of the query string. As [Clement Herreman](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6251989/why-is-my-json-encoded/6252049#6252049) also points out, the query string must be encoded.

You might want to switch to `type: "POST"` in your `.ajax()` parameters.

GET requests have a length limit that can bite you when the JSON string gets longer. POST requests have virtually no size limit.

Plus, you will cause a data leak: Query strings are written to the web server logs, possibly sensitive data could end up there when you are not careful. POST requests are logged, too. But their payload will not be logged, as it is not part of the URL.

Comment: Are you sure jQuery does it ? It thought they decided not to do it, to avoid double encoding http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/6834

Comment: @Clement: Yes, it does, I'm absolutely sure. Try it.

Comment: @Clement: I've looked at `ajax()` in the jQuery source and what it does is calling [the `param()` support function](http://www.keyframesandcode.com/resources/javascript/deconstructed/jquery/#param) which encodes the data.

Answer (score 3):

Because URL must be encoded, according the [RFC 3986](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc3986)

Hint on how to encode url using Javascript : [Encode URL in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascri)